# Joomla: Install component and module at once

Tags: joomla, module, installation, components

I know how to install a component together with a plugin. It's all about manipulating the xml like, let's say, the Artof User component.

What I want to know is if this is also applicable to module. Like I can install a component together with a module.

Comment: What version of Joomla is this for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543857/how-to-install-component-and-route-plugin-in-one-package/8613704#8613704

Answer (score 3):

Starting from J1.6, you can create a Package. See http://docs.joomla.org/Package