# Joomla 1.5 install multiple plugins

Tags: plugins, joomla, installation, package

I have developed two plugins for Joomla 2.5 and packed them into one package for simplifying the installation process for users. But now I'm trying to optimize this package for Joomla 1.5, and I can't find any method to combine these two plugins into one package for installation. Installing them separated works fine, but the manifest file (.xml) created for Joomla 2.5 package doesn't work for Joomla 1.5. Can anyone give me some tips or maybe another Joomla 1.5 package in existence as an example ?

Thank you.

Edit: These two plugins are different types of plugins. One is for 'content' and one is for 'editors-xtd'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1.5, it is not that easy.

- A similar question has been posted here: [How to install component and route plugin in one package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543857/how-to-install-component-and-route-plugin-in-one-package)
- Some further documentation for 1.5 can be found here: [Using the installer API to support package installation](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_installer_API_to_support_package_installation)
- Or here: [Install Multiple Joomla Extensions in a Single Package](http://jeffchannell.com/Joomla/install-multiple-joomla-extensions-in-a-single-package.html)

I don't think you can create a package that solely installs multiple plugins (in Joomla 1.5). You will have to create one dummy component, so that the installation php file for that component can install the plugins for you. 
You can then use the component to provide common configuration options, generic info, and a single location to update/uninstall your package.

**Note:** [Joomla 1.5 has reached end-of-life in April 2012](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_and_Migrating_Joomla)