# How to install a plugin with a template pack

Tags: joomla

J!rs,

You know that when creating an extension file you can set an install file that is fired during installation and where I can add modules and plugins using **JInstaller**.

For example, in my manifest **extension.xml**

```
<installfile>install.extension.php</installfile>
```

I wonder if it's possible to do this in a template **templateDetails.xml**

I've tried but no php file is fired, tried *installfile* and *scriptfile*

Thanks!

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543857/how-to-install-component-and-route-plugin-in-one-package) and [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Package)

Comment: he needs it for a template package

Comment: What version of Joomla! are you using? If at least 2.5, then Lodder's 2nd link should work.

Comment: I already know about package installations, put I don't want that the template installs like a package